Deploy Nextjs application with swagger generated client to Vercel
I am writing a multi-module gradle application where one of the module is spring boot backend written in java 21 and the other is NextJs frontend. The NextJs module contains a build.gradle.kts file with scripts to generate & install swagger's typescript client into node_modules.
frontend/build.gradle.kts
import com.github.gradle.node.npm.task.NpmTask

plugins {
    id("com.github.node-gradle.node") version "7.0.2"
}

Now I want to deploy the nextjs application to Vercel but I got the following error
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.2.
     Required by:
         project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.2.2
      > No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.5' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11

can I somehow configure the Vercel environment to support java 21 and gradle 8.5
